# How can I repair this gouge in my Hyundia Ioniq bumper?

Tags: hyundai, repair, body, plastic

Below are a couple of photos of my rear bumper trunk on my 2018 Hyundai Ioniq after I was rear ended by a truck. You can see that there's a clear protictive strip that is gouged as well as the paint down to the plasic.  The body shop already said there is no damage to the frame underneath by the way.  The dealer's body shop want to charge me > $1000 to do the entire bumper, but I'm thinking that if I replace the clear strip and and fill in the white gouge that it will look fine.  My question is how can I fill in something like that?  Also I'm unable to identify the strip, so I'm not sure how to order it?
Is this something anyone could advise me on?

enter image description here
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you asked about buying the strip at the parts department of your Hyundai dealer?

Comment: If you were rear ended the bumper may be damaged and you just don't see it. Bumpers these days are designed to crush, absorbing impact forces, and often they need to be replaced after impacts, even if they don't look that bad. Your body shop may be right about replacing it.

Comment: @GdD The body shop estimate only mentions removing the outer bumper to paint it.  They looked underneeth it and found the rigid frame was not crushed at all.

Answer (score 0):

The clear strip is there to protect the paint on the bumper from general day to day scuffs and scrapes as you put stuff in and out of the boot/trunk. Given that it's therefore pretty expendable, I'd expect them to sell it separately - it might be listed as "trunk sill protector" or something like that.

If not, I'd suspect you can buy aftermarket strips that you just cut to the right shape for your car, intended for those that don't have one fitted as standard - it's only a bit of sticky-back plastic after all.

If you can replace the clear strip, then the problem becomes a conventional paintwork scratch, and can be fixed in more traditional methods - rub it down with sandpaper to remove any edges, fill any deep gouges with fine car body filler, sand back smooth, then repaint or touch up with the correct colour - note that there's a surprising number of shades of white when it comes to car paint, so make sure you get the right one, using the paint code from the VIN plate.

Be sure to mask off all the areas you don't want to get paint on, and try to blend the edges as you paint it - though you won't need to worry as much as normal as it'll be partly hidden by the clear strip.

Comment: OK.  I think I've found reasonable replacement for the protective sticker, but since they are transparent, and the gouge goes all the way through the paint, how do I fill in the paint underneeth?

Comment: @Frank I've added some more to the answer about dealing with that